# Using CFDB7 vs Custom MySQL Database

Tags: php, mysql, plugin-contact-form-7

I am using Contact Form 7 in the front end to create pages.

I want to store all the user entered information into the MySQL database. Should I do it via PHP code. Could someone explain me with an example?

Answer (score 1):

> I want to store all the user entered information into the MySQL database.

In this case, you can use the plugin called [Flamingo](https://wordpress.org/plugins/flamingo/), which stores all of your messages submitted through [Contact Form 7](https://wordpress.org/plugins/contact-form-7/). It's actually made by the same plugin author.